# Pointers for using CMake with galternatives?

Tags: c++, cmake, ubuntu-14.04

I'd like to try using a newer version of CMake than is distributed with ubuntu 14.04. Consequently, I've built it from source locally and would like to install it in such a way that I can choose between the ubuntu 14.04 version of CMake and a newer one of my own building (3.0.2 or 3.1).

Does anyone have any tips they can share about using CMake with galternatives/alternatives?

TIA!

Comment: Really the questions comes down to tips and techniques for having two different versions of CMake installed simultaneously and switching back and forth between them.

Answer (score 1):

Install CMake 3.x in /opt/cmake3. To use version 3, set your `PATH` to:

```
export PATH=/opt/cmake3/bin:${PATH}
```

From now on, you can use CMake 3.x - shell will pick first cmake command it finds in `PATH`.

There are more advanced methods, but this one is so simple I'd give it a try first.

Comment: True, this does work. But I was hoping to learn if there was anything special I needed to do in order to have the version of the CMake that I'm using based on the "alternatives" system which I find works brilliantly for other packages that I want to switch back and forth between.

Comment: Yes, you can switch symlinks in /usr/bin - that's what "alternatives" system does. Try this:  `ln -s /opt/cmake/bin/cmake3 /usr/bin/cmake3`. You may need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH if `*.so` cannot be found.